# How to clone every column except the last one in the header row of a table

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Get the first tr
    var firstRow = $('.header');

    //Clone the first row
    firstRow.clone().attr('class', 'fixedHeader').prependTo('#ResultsTable');

    firstRow.find('th').each(function (i) {
        alert(i); //displays 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (6th is the hidden column that I would like to not calculate)
        var thWidth = $(this).width();

        $('.fixedHeader th').eq(i).css({
            width: thWidth
        });
    });
});
```

I am trying to clone the first row without the last column of a table. I am hiding the last column using CSS class `gLine` which is hidden from the user.
The script above still takes the hidden column and calculates the width which causes the cloned header to not match with the rest of the table:

[image]

The HTML source is:

[image]

As you can see I would like to only take from `Show Guideline` to `Summary` column and not calculate the last column but my code is calculating the last column as well.

How can I not take the last column so the cloned header column matches the table columns.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmffgowf/ (As you can see there are 7 alerts which means it is calculating the width of the last column which makes all the other column smaller)

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: `firstRow.clone().attr('class', 'fixedHeader').find('.gLine').remove().end().prependTo('#ResultsTable');` Should do it

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I will test it out and if works great, otherwise I will create a fiddle. Thanks.

Comment: That didn't work. I will post a fiddle.

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmffgowf/ (As you can see there are 7 alerts which means it is calculating the width of the last column which makes all the other column smaller)

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I did not really read your code. The snippet i gave you is working, but then, i started to read your code and realized it doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do? Why are you cloning the row without removing the old one? What is the use of cloning the row anyway? We can't really give you an answer without those informations.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I figured it would be confusing. So i hope I can clarify it. I am trying to have a fixed header to my table and hence cloning it and prepending to the table. It prepends and works great except it takes into account of the last column of the first row when calculating the width which is making all the other columns smaller and not match the displayed column of the parent table.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge then, use my code snipet along with mr. Pavlikov's answer. It *"should"* work.

Comment: :/ Still a no go. `TH` is not there anymore (which is good news) but the column width is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`firstRow.find('th:not(:last-child)')`

instead of just

`firstRow.find('th')`

Comment: The space at the end still exists however there is no width.

Answer (score 0):

Add `firstRow.remove('th:last-child');` at the end, should do the trick. Since you're cloning the whole row member-wise by the `tr` element, you need to remove it from the `clone`.

`:last-child` is a pretty specific CSS selector, should be what you're looking for.

Comment: @mr.Pavlikov used `firstRow.find('th:not(:last-child)')` but I'm pretty sure that won't work since you already made the clone and the element still exists within the clone (on the previous line: `firstRow.clone().attr('class', 'fixedHeader').prependTo('#ResultsTable');`)

Comment: @JaredHopper, you are right. It didn't work for me. The `TH` still exists :/ Do I add the line before the clone?

Comment: Just combine in one chain

`firstRow.clone().prependTo().find('th:not(:last-child)').each(function(){ // code })

Comment: I did this: `var firstRow = $('.header'); firstRow.remove('th:last-child');` but it still didn't work.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge it should be after the clone

Comment: This isn't going to get you the correct width, because you're still getting the width of the elements that exist with 7 cells... if you want to do something like that, try getting the width of the td's below it

Comment: Here is the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/hYZZnwBK Can you please tell me why the popup window when scroll past a certain point doesn't match the table below.